# How to center align pop up div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to align a pop up division to center of monitor/screen using javascript?

I tried using screen.width and screen.height to get center. But the division gets aligned to center of scrolling page vertically

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">
  This a vertically and horizontally centered popup.
</div>

<a onclick="showPopup('popup');">Show Popup</a>

<style type="text/css">
  .popup {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-50px 0 0 -100px; /* [-(height/2)px 0 0 -(width/2)px] */
    display:none;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showPopup(id) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(id);
    popup.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

**CSS explained:**
The div is 200x100, you position it 50% from the top and 50% from the left, but to have it centered fully, you need to substract from that 50% values the half of the width and height, the way to do this is to use negative margins, hence margin-top should be the negative value of the height/2 and margin-left should be the negative value of the width/2.

Answer (score 3):

How about just doing with CSS:

```
<div class="div">Some Content......</div>

.div {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: its a modal box kinda div
and i have used screen.height and screen.width properties of javascript to get the box to center.
But the box comes to vertical center of scrolling page and not to center of visible area

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 function msgBox(message)
 {
  var msgbox = document.getElementById("msgbox");
  msgbox.innerHTML = message;
  var x = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (msgbox.offsetWidth / 2);
  var y = (window.offsetHeight / 2) - (msgbox.offsetHeight / 2);              
  msgbox.style.top = y;
  msgbox.style.left = x;
  msgbox.style.display = "block";
 }
```

Comment: hi not coming in center.. may be  some mod on it might help.. but not getting it

Comment: The above two line code should be like below: 
    var x = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (msgbox.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    var y = (window.offsetHeight / 2) - (msgbox.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";

Here "px" pixel was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixed-positioning:

```
#box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 200px 30%;
}
```

It's only horizontally centered. Vertical will take some playing with. I have no idea how browsers act differently with the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this vertical centering problem on any webpage that required scrolling.

Switching to position: fixed solved it, so:

```
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-50px 0 0 -100px; /* [-(height/2)px 0 0 -(width/2)px] */
```

This worked in firefox, google chrome, safari (pc) and IE9.

Unfortunately, I wanted it to appear in front of an `pdf file` - the pop up did appear in front using Firefox, Chrome but went behind in IE9 and Safari....