# Setting pop up div at the center of the screen

Tags: javascript

I am creating a pop-up div. Its size is 521px, and height 400px.

Now I want to set it get displayed at the center of the screen or browser window irrespective of the size of the browser window.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_update_profile()
   {
       document.getElementById('black_fade').style.display='block';
       var dw = document.getElementById('div_register').style.width;
       alert(dw);
       document.getElementById('div_register').style.left= ((window.innerWidth)-dw)/2;
   }
</script>
```

The line `alert(dw);` displays the div width, but the line after that isn't working.

Comment: `getElementById.('div_register')` remove the dot in center.

Comment: shouldn't it be style.margin-left

Comment: style.margin-left would break from JS it would be marginLeft, but here is one of many solution on stackoverflow already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202583/how-to-center-align-pop-up-div-using-javascript - just see related list on the side for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output of alert(dw)? If this contains some measurement unit (like "123px") you need to parse it into an int before using it in the calculation:

```
var dw = parseInt(document.getElementById('div_register').style.width);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
//remove extra dot
document.getElementById('div_register').style.left= ((window.innerWidth)-dw)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dw` is a string ending in `px`; you'll want to call `parseInt` on it first to get the number by itself. However, using JavaScript is the long way around a problem that can be solved easily with CSS:

```
#div_register {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -200px -260px;
}
```