# message on same page (not pop up) when value is >1. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

basically i have a value "truecount" and if this value is less than one i want an error message on screen Not an alert popup.

sorry but im a noob

Comment: Where's the question? Please edit your post to include a question + your current code.

Comment: Your title says `>1`, your question says 'less than one' (`<1`); which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try considering using a javascript library like jquery.
Place in your HTML a hidden layer

When it happens that your variable truecount becomes>1
just execute somthing like
....
$('#ErrorReporting').html('Your alert Message').slideDown();

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden element and change its' style to visible when your condition is met

```
if ( truecontent < 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}


<div id="message" style="display: none">
    Your Message Here
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ABgEP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to show a message like

1. Showing alert box (But you don't want it).
2. Showing message in a `div` which is initially hidden, and shows on message.
3. Showing a popup `div` with any animation may be for good feel.

For more on `div popups` [Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202583/how-to-center-align-pop-up-div-using-javascript) or [Here](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php) or [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32147/Masked-Div-Or-Modal-Popup-Window)