# how to make popup in center of screen and overlay/background to full screen high

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am working on asp.net page. In master page I have a div like this:

```
<body id="page1" >
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- this is popup light grey show -->
            <div class="darkenBg" id="popupBackground" style="display:none;"></div>

            <!-- content -->

            <div class="greenBox2 popUpWin" id="companySigninPopup" style="display:none;">
                <div class="topWrap">
                    <!-- popup window -->
                </div>
                <div class="botWrap">
                    <div class="corner-bottom-left">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="border-bottom">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="corner-bottom-right">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am showing it like this:

```
function ShowHomePagePopup(popupId) {
    $("#" + popupId).show();
    $("#popupBackground").show();
    $('#popupBackground').height(800);
    $("#page1").addClass('hideScrollbars');
}
```

css is like this:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
.darkenBg { /*added this div after body*/
    background: url(/images/blackBg.png);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:30;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0px;
}
.popUpWin {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:31;
    width:500px;
    left:50%;
    margin:200px 0 0 -250px
}
.hideScrollbars {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    background:url(/images/bg.gif) top left repeat-x #fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

1. When the popup appears, it is centered horizontally, but vertically at the top, so it is at top mid of the screen.
2. The overlay, light grey background, means popupBackground is only 10% of the height of screen although width is 100%. How can I make it 100% high ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ --> modal dialog

Comment: I can not use jquery ui dialog because i have my custom design of popup although I am using jquery to show my custom popup with .show method.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - Please see this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202583/how-to-center-align-pop-up-div-using-javascript)

Comment: How can I make overlay height  100% ?

Comment: Sorry for the previous post. I just fix my answer. Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the Popup Window inside the overlay-div!

```
 <body id="page1" style="height: 100%;">

<form id="form2" runat="server" style="min-height: 100%;">
 <div id="content">
..

content

...


</div>
</div>

<div class="darkenBg" id="popupBackground" style="display:none;">
        <div class="greenBox2 popUpWin" id="companySigninPopup" style="display:none;">
           <div class="topWrap">
          popup window
           </div>
           <div class="botWrap">
           <div class="corner-bottom-left">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="border-bottom">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="corner-bottom-right">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Place the Overlay inside and outside your tag! ?

Comment: I can not move the div out side form because it has asp.net controls.

Comment: then you have to set the min-height of your form-tag to 100% and keep your overley inside the form. but put the popup inside your overlay div! if you set your popup box to position fixed it keeps its position even if your page is scrollable

Answer (score 8):

This is a good way to make a popup only with CSS:

The HTML code:

```
<div class="container-popup">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.container-popup {
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.popup {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #1abcb9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BS4Te/)**.

Comment: For .container-popup, why was "position: relative;" followed by "position: fixed;" specified for this class definition? Doesn't the first position attribute get replaced by the second position attribute definition?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example to simplest overlay popup

**[LINK](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-make-simple-Overlay-popup-/1966/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container-popup, #close").click(function(){
   $('.popup').hide(); $('.container-popup').hide();
  });
});
```